# VB6: WriteFile with integers

Tags: vb6, io

I wanted to write an array of integers to a file.
I have a version that writes bytes to a file. The byte version works perfectly fine.
However, the integer array version does not. It throws the error
"Write failure. Error 1784."

I don't see where I went wrong.

This is the byte version:

```
Public Function WriteBytes(Buffer() As Byte) As Long

    If WriteFile(hFile, _
                 Buffer(LBound(Buffer)), _
                 UBound(Buffer) - LBound(Buffer) + 1, _
                 WriteBytes, _
                 0) Then
     Else
        RaiseError HBF_WRITE_FAILURE
    End If
End Function
```

But this one throws an error:

```
Public Function WriteIntegers(Buffer() As Integer) As Long

    Dim lLen&
    lLen = (UBound(Buffer) - LBound(Buffer) + 1) * 4 '1 integer=4 bytes

    Dim lWritten&        

    If WriteFile(hFile, _
                 Buffer(LBound(Buffer)), _
                  lLen, _
                  lWritten, _
                 0) Then
    Else
        RaiseError HBF_WRITE_FAILURE
    End If

    WriteIntegers = lWritten

End Function
```

I am not sure where my error in the integer version is.
Does anybody see it?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lLen = (UBound(Buffer) - LBound(Buffer) + 1) * 4 '1 integer=4 bytes
```

should be

```
lLen = (UBound(Buffer) - LBound(Buffer) + 1) * 2
```

Comment: +1 Long is the 32bit integer in VBA. lenb(v) will allow you to check.